# Highest XP respawnable mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Quite a simple question: Which respawnable (i.e. non-[boss](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Category:Boss_mobs)) mob rewards the most XP on death per mob? Extra points for a list of all mobs in order.

Comment: Note: while there are mobs with high XP "per mob", the spawn rate of Endermen in the End more than 120 blocks away from islands makes them an XP per second source only second to the [Ender Dragon farming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU-XMCJx6Ew). Never mind their hatred of endemites makes for very fast "transport" in a [farm](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=enderman+xp+farm) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the Baby Zombies actually take the cake at 12 experience *per mob* (as of 1.11).

However, for *standard* spawnable mobs, it's a tie between the Blaze/Evoker/Guardian, at 10 experience per mob.

The only other suggestion to this is the Slime/Magma Cube. While each *individual mob* only drop a miniscule amount (4 for Large, 2 for Medium, and 1 for Small), if you consider the possibility that it has the chance to split into 4, then 4 again upon death, a Large Magma Cube/Slime can drop up to 28 experience.

Jockeys also drop an additional amount of experience, though technically not a *single mob*, and can drop *additional* experience, if the Jockey is carrying equipment (i.e. a weapon/tool/armour).

```
Mob                XP
---------------------
Magma Cube/Slime   28
 Large             4
 Medium            2
 Small             1
Baby Zombie/
Zombie Villager/
Husk/
Zombie Pigman      12
Blaze              10
Evoker             10
Guardian           10
Ghast              5
Zombie/
Zombie Villager/
Husk/
Zombie Pigman      5*
Creeper            5
Shulker            5
Silverfish         5
Skeleton/
Stray              5*
Vindicator         5
Witch              5
Wither             5

*Drop additional 1-3 experience per equipment item (excluding Pigman 
variant); granting a potential total of 20.
```

Jockeys, if counted as a "Single" Mob, can award up to:

```
Mob               XP
--------------------
Chicken Jockey    15
Spider Jockey     25
Skelton Horseman  8
```

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Experience_amounts_by_source)

Comment: My info was based off dated sources so.  Good answer

Answer (score 0):

Zombie Pigman are actually the best, not baby. Babies drop 5xp, and adults drop 12.

But yes, slime spawners are very op for xp, but another good choice is blaze, guardian or enderman. Endermen may drop 5xp, but they spawn on a higher rate then blazes.